# Classifying in R: Return row number by finding the row where a value is true

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a categorical dataframe where categories are in the leftmost column and values are in the values to the right, which looks like this:

```
car  Chevy  Honda   Toyota
food Ritz   Hershey Nestle
shoe Nike   UA      Reebok
```

I'd like to take a vector and assign categories to them so a vector

```
Toyota, UA, Reebok, Nestle
```

will return

```
car, shoe, shoe, food
```

It sounds easy enough to do (and probably is), but `%in%` only works when matching a value in a vector, so I'm not sure how to do this.
How can I do this across an entire dataframe?

Comment: can you post the code you are working on, so that it will be easy to try on my end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there might be easier ways but you can try

```
dat <- read.table(text="
car  Chevy  Honda   Toyota
food Ritz   Hershey Nestle
shoe Nike   UA      Reebok", header=F, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Set up a lookup table

```
library(reshape2)
long <- melt(dat, 'V1')
```

Match on the lookup table

```
test <- c('Toyota', 'UA', 'Reebok', 'Nestle')
long$V1[match(test, long$value)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This accomplished exactly what I wanted in only a couple lines of code

Answer (score 1):

Since this appears to assume all fields in the frame are `character`, we can treat the frame as a `matrix`. (I generally discourage using `apply` with frames, so I'm including this leading caveat.)

```
df <- read.table(header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
car  Chevy  Honda   Toyota
food Ritz   Hershey Nestle
shoe Nike   UA      Reebok")
vec <- c('Toyota','UA','Reebok','Nestle')
```

Starting to looking for matches:

```
apply(df, 1, function(row) vec %in% row)
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Now we can work on this resulting matrix to return which is the first column in each row:

```
apply(apply(df, 1, function(row) vec %in% row), 1,
      function(a) which(a)[1])
# [1] 1 3 3 2
```

Now we just need to use this to index on the first column:

```
df$V1[ apply(apply(df, 1, function(row) vec %in% row), 1,
             function(a) which(a)[1]) ]
# [1] "car"  "shoe" "shoe" "food"
```

If everything is a `character` (and you have a lot of data), you might find a `matrix` to be faster.